# Depending icon at visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, slds, svg-icon

I would like to insert a picture depending on the type at my visualforce page.

My code below does n't work, could you help me please.

```
<span class="slds-icon_container" style="background-color: #49648C;">
   <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon slds-icon_small">
      <use xlink:href="{!IF(wl.objectlabel = 'Event', {!URLFOR($Asset.SLDS, 'assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#event')}, 
                         IF(wl.objectlabel = 'Task',  {!URLFOR($Asset.SLDS, 'assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#task')},
                         ''))
                       }" />
      </svg>
   </span>
```

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis for your outer IF statement.  To avoid basic errors like this, you should use a text editor that provides bracket pairing or highlighting.

Comment: I changed my code above but I get the same error. Any ideas where a parenthesis is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used another way.

```
                <span class="slds-icon_container" style="background-color: #49648C;">
                    <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon slds-icon_small">
                        <use xlink:href="/apexpages/slds/latest/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#{!IF(wl.objectlabel = 'Event', 'event',
                                         IF(wl.objectlabel = 'Task', 'task',
                                         IF(wl.objectlabel = 'EMail', 'email',
                                         IF(wl.objectlabel = 'Note', 'note',
                                         IF(wl.objectlabel = 'File', 'file',
                                         '')))))}"/>
                    </svg>
                </span>
```